# system test run error message

Tags: c#

I am trying to run this system test. I made sure that the device information is in the database.

When I ran the test it constantly gives me an error message:

> Test method SystemTests.Tests.EmailNotification.TestAddDeviceToAccount
>   threw exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains
>   no elements.

any help please

```
public void TestAddDeviceToAccount()//Test to AssDeviceToAccount
{
    //string Fccid = "OPS2";
    //string SerialNumber = "101";
    //string emailAddress = "m.koneru2@spectrumBridge.com";

    using (WSPlusEntities dc = WSPlusEntities.GetContext())
    {
         Device d1 = dc.Devices.Where(d => d.FCCID == "OPS2" && d.SerialNumber == "101").Single();
         d1.NetworkId = 1;
         //var deviceList = dc1.Devices.Where(d => d.FCCID == "OPS2" && d.SerialNumber == "102").ToList();
         //foreach (var d2 in deviceList)
         //d2.NetworkId = 1;
         dc.SaveChanges();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Check the values in `dc.Devices`. It is most likely empty.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it would appear that your linq query isn't returning any elements from the database.  You've checked the device info is in there, but the sequence (`dc.Devices`) is returning empty.

Check these things:

- The data is definitely in the correct database table
- Remove the `Where()` clause as this may be filtering wrong
- Check the app.config to ensure you're pointing at the correct database